# How to change font color of hint of TextInputLayout without changing the already set typeface?

Tags: java, android, android-textinputlayout

I am trying to change the hint color of **TextInputLayout** programatically, although I have found a way to change the hint color by creating different **styles** for different states for eg:

```
<style name="TextInputError" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/errorRed</item>
</style>
```

is set when i need to show validation error.

But what this is doing right now is changing the color but also changing the TypeFace I have set to it as well.

I am setting the TypeFace by creating a custom widget:-

```
public class CustomTextInputLayout extends TextInputLayout {
    private Typeface tf;

    public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null);
    }


    private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/gt_eesti_pro_display_regular.otf");
        if (attrs != null) {
            TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomTextView);
            String fontName = a.getString(R.styleable.CustomTextView_fontName);

            if (fontName != null) {
                tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/" + fontName);
            }
            a.recycle();
        }
        setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

I did try to use this method inside the CustomTextInputLayout class.

```
setHintTextAppearance(R.style.TextInputError);
```

But this works only initially when the views are created. When I set the style from inside the activity it not only changes the style but the font changes as well.

```
binding.tilEmail.setHintTextAppearance(R.style.TextInputError);
```

I have tried using fontFamily in the style attribute, but that didn't help. 
Is there any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following way to change Hint Color without changing TypeFace.

**[1] Create following style**

```
<style name="AppTheme.TextInputLayoutHintText" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/grayTextColor</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/_12sp</item>
</style>


<style name="AppTheme.TextInputLayoutAppearance" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
    <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/AppTheme.TextInputLayoutHintText</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryText</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/grayTextColor</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/grayEditTextBackgroundTintColor</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/grayEditTextBackgroundTintColor</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/grayEditTextBackgroundTintColor</item>
</style>
```

**[2] Use above style in your layout.xml**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutMobileNumber"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_30dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/buttonForgotPasscode"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TextInputLayoutAppearance"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/layoutCountryCode"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/layoutCountryCode"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layoutCountryCode">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextMobileNumber"
        style="@style/AppTheme.EditTextMobileNumber"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/hint_mobile_number" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

> Note that we will use `android.theme` attribute to style TextInputLayout
>
> `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TextInputLayoutAppearance"`

**[3] Now set TypeFace for TextInputLayout in your code file**

```
val typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.poppins_regular)

if (typeface != null){
    textInputLayoutMobileNumber.typeface = typeface
}
```

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for sharing this, but what I want to do is change the color of the hint of TextInputLayout dynamically (While keeping the typeface unchanged), say for example if i want to show error in input i want the color as red, or if i want to show that input is correct i want the color of the hint as green. And that is only possible if I use the **style** attribute, not the **android.theme** attribute as I dont think i can assign android.theme dynamically?